# something like enumerate in python for jquery?

Tags: jquery, each

I need something like enumerate in python, but in JQuery.

I have this small snippet:

```
array_of_urls = [....];

items = $('p[id^="gallery_thumb"]'); // get all <p> which id begins with gallery_thumb

for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    // something something with items, i and array_of_urls 
    // like:

    items[i].load( array_of_urls[i] );
}
```

is there a way to avoid the for loop and do it inline? like a mix between jquery .each and enumerate in python..

or some cleaner way to face a problem like this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`each` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) gives you an index that you can use to access the array:

```
array_of_urls = [....];

$('p[id^="gallery_thumb"]').each(function(i, e){
  $(e).load(array_of_urls[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing, I think, is this:

```
$("p[id^=gallery_thumb]").each(function (idx) {
   $(this).load(array_of_urls[idx]);
});
```